# Java obfuscators

Tags: java, obfuscation

I'm looking for a good Java obfuscator.

I've done initial research into the following Java obfuscators: proguard, yguard, retroguard, dasho, allatori, jshrink, smokescreen, jobfuscate, marvin, jbco, jode, javaguard, jarg, joga, cafebabe, donquixote, mwobfu, bbmug, zelix klassmaster, sandmark, jcloak, thicket, blufuscator, and java code protector.

I tried proguard and it has a really nice GUI, seems really stable, and seems to be the most popular, but it seemed to not like some enumeration on a referenced jar file (not within the code I was trying to obfuscate) which was weird.  Yguard seems to require some interaction with ant, which I didn't know too much about.

What is a good java obfuscator?  It doesn't need to be free, it just needs to work well and be easy to use.

Comment: also important: i have quite a big project that does include reflection and enumeration

Comment: Could you explain why you need a obfuscator?  You can't get get good stack traces if you obfuscator it...

Comment: I need an obfuscator because the project I work for wants to protect its code from competitors

Comment: You also need an obfuscator/shrinker because it will often make your distributable JAR *much* smaller.

Comment: see my review at http://stackoverflow.com/a/26717791/2132826

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I use [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net) heavily for all my release builds and I have found it is excellent.  I can't recommend it enough!

I *have* encountered obscure bugs caused by it's optimizations on several occasions and I now disable optimizations across the board - haven't had a problem caused by ProGuard since.  Though, to be fair, these were all quite some versions ago - YMMV.

I used to use the GUI *only* to get a config started, and then I resort to editing the text config myself, which is really very simple to do.  These days I do the config by hand.

I have quite complex projects all of which involve dynamic loading and reflection.  I also heavily use reflection for a callback implementation.  ProGuard has coped with these very well.

EDIT: We also use DashO Pro for one of our products - I looked into it for packaging the products I am responsible for and concluded that it's configuration was too convoluted and complex; also integrating it into the build script seemed like a bit of a pain.  But again, to be fair, this was circa 2001... so it might be better in current versions.

Comment: DashO build script support includes both a command line interface as well as an Ant task.

Comment: @lawrence You are creating a jar first then you are using GUI of proguard ? I am doing the exact but having this while using GUI .

      (https://www.guardsquare.com/proguard/manual/troubleshooting#duplicateclass)
Warning: there were 755 classes in incorrectly named files.

Comment: @WaheedKhan : Yes, I create JARs and then obfuscate them. The warning you are seeing will be because either the filename doesn't match the classname, or the relative file path in the JAR doesn't match the package name. You should inspect the JAR and verify both for the listed files.

Answer (score 11):

A good collection of links to free and commercial tools is given in this arcticle

["Protect Your Java Code - Through Obfuscators And Beyond"](http://www.excelsior-usa.com/articles/java-obfuscators.html)

The author also discusses the strong and weak points of bytecode obfuscation

Comment: +1 for linking an awesome article.

Answer (score 3):

What is the issue with ProGuard ? (which is recommended both by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150653) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93290/best-java-obfuscation-application-for-size-reduction)).

There is a section of [troubleshooting](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html) about enumerator, but they seem to be taken into account [just fine](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#enumerations).

However, Obfuscation breaks some attempts at reflection, even though modern obfuscators can detect and to some extend adjust usages of reflection in the code they're obfuscating.

Comment: The issue is that the application uses code in an external jar, and I've "kept" the files that use enumeration in my own jar code, but at run time I'm still getting problems inside the external jar's code that relates to enumeration.  I've followed the proguard troubleshooting the best I could.

Comment: Do you have the error messages that Proguard generates ?

Comment: yes, I posted it as an answer in this thread

Comment: hi VonC, I have trouble using proguard. I have 3 class files which I am packaging into one jar(with manifest). Now when I issue command : java -jar myjar.jar @myjar.pro I expect an output jar like myjar_out.jar stated in myjar.pro. But, that command runs the jar instead of creating a output jar.

Comment: According to http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/usage.html , aren't you supposed to type `java -jar proguard.jar @myjar.pro`? Because I can confirm that `java -jar myjar.jar ...` will execute the main class found in myjar.jar.

Comment: Oh yes...my bad...what was I thinking...:-). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I used Zelix Klassmaster in a commercial application for several years and found it to be excellent. I threw quite a few resources at the obfuscated code, and was not able to "break" it. It's pricey, but good.

I only stopped using it when my version got old enough that the upgrade cost was significant. My needs had changed and I didn't really need to obfuscate the classes anymore. However, if the need arises again, I'd pay for it and use it in a flash.

Cheers,

-Richard

Comment: I use this a long time ago too. It is very good. Additionally IntellJ Idea plugin is available. http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2006/08/analyzing-external-stack-traces/

Answer (score 1):

We are using Zelix Klassmaster for couple years and I can recommend it.

Comment: agree with you. see also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26717791/2132826

Comment: is it possible to obfuscate double quote string also ? we are using proguard currently in android studio.but, some limitations are there. thats why, we are searching for other tool dexguard commercial,klassmaster.

Comment: Yes, AFAIK. Never met any issues with double quoted strings.

Answer (score 1):

I use and suggest [Zelix](http://www.zelix.com) - 100% - very solid and robust protection

Comment: is it possible to obfuscate double quote string also ? we are using proguard currently in android studio.but, some limitations are there. thats why, we are searching for other tool dexguard commercial,klassmaster.