# Android Proguard - Can I skip it?

Tags: android, google-play, screenshot

I am seeing some weird crashes on my Android application when I turn on proguard obfuscation. I understand I can debug this and skip obfuscation for those classes but my question is - Is it worth the risk of having the application crash on some phone or some code path that I might not have tested/exercised. For e.g [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7628638/android-proguard-obfuscated-code-is-causing-nullpointerexception-when-it-really) talks about one such device specific error due to proguard.
I am close to release and am now wondering is it worth introducing proguard at this point. I understand I should have tested with it right from the start ..made a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, the common problems with Proguard is not setting the correct parameters for third party libraries.
Make sure you've followed the instructions given by the third party providers as to the additions to the proguard.cfg file.
Anyhow, to disable proguard, you can always edit your `project.properties` file and remove the `proguard.config=proguard.cfg` line

Comment: Thanks. I am not confident at this point to enable progaurd. Hence I will take my chances and remove it from the properties file. Thanks.

Comment: I've NEVER had any problems with any piece of code (with almost 100 projects) using Proguard. I assume your problem is with a 3rd party lib. If you don't mind having people decompile your code and easily reading it, you can skip obfuscation