# Strange NPE: primitive field null inside instance method

Tags: java, android

I'm having a strange NPE with the following stacktrace:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'int com.foo.gvpclient.x.c' on a null object reference
       at com.foo.gvpclient.GVPConfiguration.getDeviceTypeAsString(GVPConfiguration.java:507)
       at com.foo.gvpclient.request.uniapi.authentication.LoginAnonymousRequest.<init>(LoginAnonymousRequest.java:39)
       at com.foo.bar.analytics.managers.AnalyticsManager.sendEventsBatchAsAnonymous(AnalyticsManager.java:489)
       at com.foo.bar.analytics.managers.AnalyticsManager.addEvent(AnalyticsManager.java:324)
       at com.foo.bar.analytics.managers.AnalyticsManager.onBrowseEvent(AnalyticsManager.java:266)
       at com.foo.bar.analytics.managers.AnalyticsManager.onBrowseEvent(AnalyticsManager.java:231)
       at com.foo.bar.analytics.managers.AnalyticsManager.onBrowseEvent(AnalyticsManager.java:711)
       at com.foo.bar.login.activities.LoginActivity.register(LoginActivity.java:469)
       at com.foo.bar.login.activities.LoginActivity.access$register(LoginActivity.java:51)
       at com.foo.bar.login.activities.LoginActivity$onCreate$$inlined$apply$lambda$1.onClick(LoginActivity.java:123)
       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7339)
       at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:14221)
       at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7305)
       at android.view.View.access$3200(View.java:846)
       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27787)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7076)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
```

This is `getDeviceTypeAsString()` method:

```
public String getDeviceTypeAsString() {
    return String.valueOf(this.mDeviceType);
}
```

where `mDeviceType` is declared as

```
private int mDeviceType;
```

Please correct me if I'm wrong but there's nothing here that can be null.

For the sake of completion, the method is called from here:

```
public LoginAnonymousRequest(GVPConfiguration gvpConfig) {
    super(gvpConfig);
    // More unrelated stuff
    this.mQueryStringParams.put("deviceType", this.mGvpConfig.getDeviceTypeAsString());
}
```

Again, correct me if I'm wrong but if `gvpConfig` is null in the constructor above, then the NPE would have been thrown at `this.mGvpConfig.getDeviceTypeAsString()` and not inside the method itself.

So what's causing this NPE? Could it be something related to code obfuscation?

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint in the constructor and debug it? What obfuscation tool do you use?

Comment: @lugiorgi I can't debug the obfuscated/optimized version.

Comment: makes sense, I did not understand that the NPE only occurs after obfuscation/optimization.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to answer: we use standard Android tooling for that, so Proguard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not obfuscation but optimization done by the same tooling such as proguard or r8.

Basically, the simple accessor is optimized as inline in the caller and it's in fact the `GVPConfiguration` object at call site that is null.

Comment: So related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7628638/android-proguard-obfuscated-code-is-causing-nullpointerexception-when-it-really?

Comment: Yeah I meant obfuscation/optimization. That's the only possible explanation for this NPE.

Comment: @lugiorgi Yes looks like the same issue there.